# Open CV camera in Android app landscape mode

Tags: java, android, opencv, camera

I am developing an Android app in landscape mode and use Open CV camera.  However whenever I open camera, only middle part of the camera frame is shown and other parts are cut off.  The code is fine in portrait mode.  Is there a way that can show the camera frame same as in the portrait mode?  Or can I only change the java camera to portrait?

I have tried convert Mat to Bitmap and then rotate it.  But it has error saying the dimension is not the same.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.width(), image.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(image, bitmap);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
// matrix.preScale(0f, -1.0f);
matrix.postRotate(90);
Bitmap input = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, false);
Utils.bitmapToMat(input, image);
```

Here is my code

MainActivity.java

```
    cameraBridgeViewBase.setCvCameraViewListener(new CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCameraViewStopped() {

        }

        @Override
        public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
            Mat image = inputFrame.rgba();
            Log.d("Loader", String.valueOf(inputFrame.rgba().height()));

            return image;
        }
    });
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
    android:id="@+id/cameraViewer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Camera cut the middle part]

[image: Camera frame in the portrait mode]